Create a time chart in Ruby with Tk::Tcllib::Plotchart::Timechart
I'm going to create a time chart in Ruby with the class Tk::Tcllib::Plotchart::Timechart for a statistic data, which value is generated along with the time. However it doesn't work for me. I've tried first with simple Ruby example, to create a [time, value] chart, in order to learn how the ::Timechart works. But run of the example shows only an empty window, without drawing a line/chart for the given data.
Who may kindly give me a help to have a look into the code followed here, or provide me an runable example.
Thanks a lot!
Yan
    require 'tk'
    require 'tkextlib/tcllib/plotchart'
    require 'date'

    # Sample data: array of [DateTime, value] arrays
    data = [
      [DateTime.new(2023, 8, 1), 10],
      [DateTime.new(2023, 8, 2), 15],
      [DateTime.new(2023, 8, 3), 7],
      [DateTime.new(2023, 8, 4), 20],
      [DateTime.new(2023, 8, 5), 14],
    ]

    # Convert DateTime to string format expected by Timechart
    data = data.map { |datetime, value| [datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), value] }

    # Create the main window
    root = TkRoot.new { title "Timechart Example" }

    # Create a Canvas to hold the Timechart and labels
    canvas = TkCanvas.new(root) { width 800; height 400 }
    canvas.pack

    # Create a Timechart
    timechart = Tk::Tcllib::Plotchart::Timechart.new(canvas, 
      data.first[0],  # start date
      data.last[0],   # end date
      5              # vertical spacing
    )
    timechart.pack

    # Add x-axis label
    x_label = TkLabel.new(root) do
      text 'Date'
      font TkFont.new('Arial 12 bold')
      pack(side: 'bottom', pady: 20) # Adjust pady for spacing
    end

    # Add y-axis label
    y_label = TkLabel.new(root) do
      text 'Value'
      font TkFont.new('Arial 12 bold')
      # Position label to the left of the canvas
      place(x: 30, y: 200, anchor: 'center') # Adjust x, y, and anchor as needed
    end


    # Start the Tk main event loop
    Tk.mainloop


The problem with your chart it that it does not contain data that can be shown, making you think that it does not work. Moreover, it looks like you cannot initialize the timechart with the DateTime objects.
Start by adding data to your chart, and see how it fits your needs.
Here is a modified part of your code, which does show data in the chart.
# Create a Timechart
timechart = Tk::Tcllib::Plotchart::Timechart.new(canvas,
    "1 january 2004",
    "2 february 2004",
  2
)
timechart.period('study', '6 january 2004', '9 january 2004')
timechart.vertline( 'jan', '2 january 2004')
timechart.pack
canvas.pack

From this as a starting point, have a look at the timechart functions and try them out, looking at their effect.
